# add DataTable data not working?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to get the method `data.SetValue(...)` working in the asynchronous callback in method `getNames`. Unfortunately it doesn't work. `data.setValue(...)` *does* work in the synchronous method `createColumnChartView`.

What could be the cause of this problem? Please explain why setting data doesn't work in `getNames`. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget; 
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.ColumnChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.CoreChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options;
import com.practicum.client.Product;
import com.practicum.client.rpc.ProductService;
import com.practicum.client.rpc.ProductServiceAsync;


public class DataOutColumnChart {
private final DataTable data = DataTable.create();
private final Options options = CoreChart.createOptions();
private final ProductServiceAsync productService = GWT.create(ProductService.class);

public DataOutColumnChart(Runnable runnable) {
}

public Widget createColumnChartView() {
    /* create a datatable */
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Price");
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "EUR");
    data.addRows(2);
    data.setValue(0, 0, "Bar 1");
    data.setValue(0, 1, 123);
    getNames();

    /* create column chart */
    options.setWidth(400);
    options.setHeight(300);
    options.setBackgroundColor("#e8e8e9");

    return new ColumnChart(data, options);
}

public void getNames() {
    productService.getNames(new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<Product>>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        }

        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Product> result) {
            for (Product p : result) {
                data.setValue(0, 0, "Bar 2"); // DONT WORK, NOTHING HAPPENS
                data.setValue(0, 1, 345); // DONT WORK, NOTHING HAPPENS
                System.out.println("Bla bla test"); // THIS WORKS
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you're setting data to a `DataTable` that has *already been rendered*. Your Asynchronous call in `getNames()` completes too slowly to affect the `DataTable` in time for the rendering of the `ColumnChart`. Even if it *did* complete fast enough, it would always be a race condition. Ideally, you would not actually render that chart until *after* you've received all necessary data from the RPC call.

Another option is to store a reference to that `ColumnChart` and call `columnChart.draw(...)` after you get your data back from RPC.

**Edit:**

Here's the example you requested.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget; 
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.ColumnChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.CoreChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.Options;
import com.practicum.client.Product;
import com.practicum.client.rpc.ProductService;
import com.practicum.client.rpc.ProductServiceAsync;


public class DataOutColumnChart {
    private final DataTable data = DataTable.create();
    private final Options options = CoreChart.createOptions();
    private final ProductServiceAsync productService = GWT.create(ProductService.class);
    private ColumnChart chart = null;

    public DataOutColumnChart(Runnable runnable) {
    }

    public void initColumnChart() {
        /* create a datatable */
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Price");
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "EUR");

        /* create column chart */
        options.setWidth(400);
        options.setHeight(300);
        options.setBackgroundColor("#e8e8e9");

        chart = new ColumnChart(data, options);
    }

    public void getNames() {
        productService.getNames(new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<Product>>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            }

            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Product> result) {
                if (result != null && result.size() > 0) {
                    // if there is data...
                    data.addRows(result.size()); // add a row for each result
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                        // loop through the results
                        Product product = result.get(i); // get out the product
                        // ...then set the column values for this row
                        data.setValue(i, 0, product.getSomeProperty());
                        data.setValue(i, 1, product.getSomeOtherProperty());
                    }
                    updateChart();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateChart() {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank for you reply,

I'm not good in Java programming...
Could you please give me an example based on my code?
Thanks!

Comment: @Calvin There you go. I didn't test it, but it should work just fine.